# How to add extra condition in linq when doing join on 2 or more table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

Here is my query.

```
var Result = (
    from t1 in dbContext.Table1
    join t2 in dbContext.Table2 on t1.Id equals t2.Id
    join t3 in dbContext.Table3 on t1.Id equals t3.Id
    where
    && t1.CategoryUId == Input.CategoryUId
    select new CategoryInfo
    {
        Table1ID = t1.Id,
        Table1Name = t1.Name,
        TableTypeUid = t1.TypeUId,
        ProductName = t2.ProductName,
        BrandName = t3.BrandName
    }
).ToList();
```

Here I wanted to add extra con in second line :-

```
join t2 in dbContext.Table2 on t1.Id equals t2.Id && t2.Active=true
```

But it is not taking, giving me error.

How to add that?

Can we add extra condition in second line.

Tried :

```
var Result = (
    from t1 in dbContext.Table1
    join t2 in dbContext.Table2 on t1.Id equals t2.Id
    join t3 in dbContext.Table3 on t1.Id equals t3.Id
    where                                       
    && t1.CategoryUId == Input.CategoryUId
    select new CategoryInfo
    {
        Table1ID = t1.Id,
        Table1Name = t1.Name,
        TableTypeUid = t1.TypeUId,
        ProductName = t2.ProductName,
        BrandName = t3.BrandName}).ToList();
```

Here I wanted to add extra con in second line :-

```
 join t2 in dbContext.Table2 on t1.Id equals t2.Id && t2.Active=true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either do

```cs
join t2 in dbContext.Table2.Where(t2 => t2.Active) on t1.Id equals t2.Id
```

which you should *always* do if you are doing a left-join using `DefaultIfEmpty`

Or you can add it into the `where`

```cs
where  // what goes here??
    && t1.CategoryUId == Input.CategoryUId
    && t2.Active
```

---

Note that C# uses `==` not `=` for comparison, and that `bool` does not need it anyway, you can just use the value directly. `someBool == true` is the same as `someBool`, and `someBool == false`  is the same as `!someBool`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `join` with `from` and `Where` condition. It is documented in [Complex Query Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators#collection-selector-references-outer-in-a-where-clause)

```cs
    ...
    from t1 in dbContext.Table1
    from t2 in dbContext.Table2.Where(t2 => t1.Id == t2.Id && t2.Active)
    join t3 in dbContext.Table3 on t1.Id equals t3.Id
    ...
```